# print jodamoney without decimals

Tags: java, joda-money

I know how to print a joda-money object using the `MoneyFormatterBuilder`:

```
Money m = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, 48209);
System.out.println(new MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.ASCII_DECIMAL_POINT_GROUP3_COMMA).toFormatter().print(m));
```

But this prints it with decimals:

```
48,209.00
```

How do I print a joda-money object with no decimals? And have it round up if necessary? So that the output of the above would be:

```
48,209
```

And (another example) `48209.69` would print `48210`?

Comment: Did you look at the [Money API](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org/joda/money/Money.html)? Shouldn't that be enough to allow you to do what you need to do?

Comment: I did. This is as far as I got

Comment: you can use BigMoney

Answer (score 0):

You can rounding money and then get string value out of it and replace decimal places.

```
@Test
void formatMoney() {
    Arrays.asList(10.44d, 10.45d, 10.46d, 10.50d, 10.55d).forEach(
            d -> {

                Money money = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, d);

                LOGGER.info("Money with decimal: {}\tRounded money: {}\tFormatted string out of money: {}",
                    money,
                    money.rounded(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP),                
                    money.rounded(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString().replace(".00","")); 
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigMoney`.

Try with this:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("48209.60");
BigMoney m = BigMoney.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, bigDecimal.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
System.out.println(new MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.ASCII_DECIMAL_POINT_GROUP3_COMMA).toFormatter().print(m));
```